# Error 3078 over WAN

Tags: ms-access, vb6, error-handling, jet, wan

In a `VB6` app accessing a `MDB` database file over a WAN there are occasionally `3078` errors due to network connectivity issues:

> Error 3078: The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input
>   table or query "table_name". Make sure it exists and that its name
>   is spelt correctly.

How should the app deal with this sort of error?  Should it just display a message suggesting the user try again later, or should the app try the database query a few more times and then give up?

Is there way in a VB6-MDB app to deal with this issue globally, rather than having to write a special error handler for each query in the app?

Comment: Even using a client/server DBMS you're subject to network issues.  Once you leave the comfort of a LAN these become too likely to ignore.  While I'm not a fan of building any kind of "data access layer" on top of ADO or DAO, at least that might offer you a way to centralize things like retries.  However even then your code needs to deal with a retry failure at each point of use - a given update might be part of a loop nested deep in several layers of procedure calls, etc.

Comment: Are WAN network 'drop-outs' something that can be dealt with by doing about 10 or 20 re-tries and then giving up?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd want to retry more than 2 or 3 times automatically.  At that point you almost need to notify the user and let them trigger any additional retries manually.  If this is an unattended process maybe back off for some interval and then rety again or log the error and give up.

Comment: @Bob77: what if the application is starting up and needs to access the database file?  Should the app just display an error message and then just die?